# Subset of metric space

Tags: analysis

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and let $Y$ be a nonempty subset of $X$. Show that $d$ defines a metric space on $Y$.

I'm not sure how to go about this, I was thinking of just checking the properties hold in $Y$, but not sure if that's the correct approach.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You will have to check if the properties hold on $Y$, use that they hold on $X$.

Comment: It *is* the correct approach. Just verify that the required properties of $d$ also hold in $Y$.

Comment: Isn't that trivial though?

Comment: Indeed it is trivial.

Comment: @Alti Happy to help. I added my comment as an answer to make it easier for others to spot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed the correct approach. Just verify that the required properties of $d$ also hold in $Y$. As you have noticed, it is trivial to do so.